# How can i access a linked list that is implement by me form outside of class

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a linked list that store bunch of instrument as an object. And i want to access and display it on a GUI. What are some good ways to access it instead of just create a method and return the list to the GUI.

Pls gives some advice.
I will be appreciated.

Comment: If you have created a linkedList class then why dont you import the class and create object, where exactly are you stuck ? please post the code to understand your problem

Comment: Pls check the comment below for a update

Answer (score 0):

It depends if you mean the class or an instance of your class. If you mean a class its just an import.
 If you need an instance of a class there are other ways like making it static (quick and dirty) or using a singleton if just one copy is allowed.

Comment: I have a class that reads a txt file by using scanner and stored the information on a linked list(it is not java built in, I created my own).  And I would like to access the list on a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

```
class InstrumentDisplayPanel extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
            JPanel status = new JPanel();
            JPanel action = new JPanel();
            JLabel name = new JLabel();
            JLabel number = new JLabel();
            JButton next = new JButton("next");
            JButton previous = new JButton("previous");

            InstrumentDisplayPanel() {
                this.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,200));
                DoublyLinkedList<Instrument> instrumentList = FileRead.loadInstrument();
                Node tempNode = instrumentList.getFirstItem();
                Item tempItem = (Item)tempNode.getItem();
                name.setText(tempItem.getName());
                number.setText(tempItem.getNumber());
                status.add(name);
                status.add(number);

                action.add(next);
                action.add(previous);

                add(status);
                add(action);

            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                if (event.getSource() == next) {

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: As a update for my question, if i want to change the name and number label on my panel to the next item on by linkedList. Is it possible to do by using an actionListener. I apologize for any miss understanding for my question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static DoublyLinkedList<MusicSheet> loadMusicSheet(){
        System.out.println("I am loading");
        Scanner musicSheetInput = null;
        try
        {
            musicSheetInput = new Scanner(new File("musicSheet.txt"));
        }
        catch(FileNotFoundException instrument)
        {
            System.out.println("File does Not Exist Please Try Again: ");
        }

        DoublyLinkedList<MusicSheet> musicSheetList = new DoublyLinkedList<MusicSheet>();
        while (musicSheetInput.hasNextLine()){
            String name = musicSheetInput.next();
            String number = musicSheetInput.next();
            String description = musicSheetInput.nextLine();
            if(name.equals("GuitarSheet")){
                musicSheetList.add(new GuitarSheet(name,number,description));
            }
            else if(name.equals("ViolinSheet")){
                musicSheetList.add(new ViolinSheet(name,number,description));
            }
            else if(name.equals("CelloSheet")){
                musicSheetList.add(new  CelloSheet(name,number, description));
            }
        }
        musicSheetList.display();
        return musicSheetList;
    }
```

Comment: another update to my question is that my linked list came from a file. How can I access this linked list at another class(example my GUI). Is it possible to do without Re-Reading this file. Pls help.